# How can I convert a string to a char array in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript

How do you convert a string into a char array in ActionScript 3.0?

I tried the below code but I get an error:

```
var temp:ByteArray =  new ByteArray();
temp = input.toCharArray();
```

From the error, I understand that the toCharArray() function cannot be applied to a string (i.e in my case - input). Please help me out. I am a beginner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if this helps your purpose but you can use [String#split()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29):

> If you use an empty string ("") as a delimiter, each character in the string is placed as an element in the array.

```
var array:Array = "split".split("");
```

Now you can get individual elements using index

```
array[0] == 's' ; array[1] == 'p' ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to do with it, the individual characters can also be accessed with string.charAt(index), without splitting them into an array.